# Is it possible to modify function call with minimum code change?

Tags: c++

I guess what I want to do is something like this (expressed like a marco).

```
    #define x->send(str)  x->send(my(x, str))
```

inside function "my"

```
    char *my(X x, char *d)
    {
        strcat(d, x->name);  // assuming no memory problem
    }
```

Basically, need to attach more information about x. Of course, there are other ways around. But I want to keep minimum changes to the code, and there is no way to modify the X class. Thank you!

Sample code listed below.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define x->send(y)    (x->send(my(x,y)))

    class H
    {
    public:

      char name[16];

      void send(char *str)
      {
        printf("%s", str);
      }

      H()
      {
        strcpy(name, "adam");
      }
    };

    char *my(H x, char *y)
    {
      strcat (y, "from ");
      return strcat(y, x->name);
    }

    int main()
    {
      H *h = new H;

      char str[32];
      strcpy(str, "hello ");

      h->send(str);

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Is `#define x->send(str)  x->send(my(x, str))` legal?

Comment: @Luchian: Even if it was (which it very much is not), it's not going to help. What if they name the variable `y` instead?

Comment: @NicolBolas I know it's not, I was hinting it to the op... ;)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I think he already knows. He wants a solution that would be similar to that macro.

Comment: The legality of `#define x->send(str) x->send(my(x, str))` depends largely on your definition of 'legal'.  When pre-processed with `gcc -E -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -pedantic`, you get the warning `ISO C99 requires whitespace after the macro name`.  Otherwise, it is a legal definition of an object-like macro `x`.  It does *not* do what the question asker wants (a mention of `x` becomes `->send(str) x->send(my(x, str))`), but it is 'legal'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a wrapper class.

```
class DiagnosticH : public H {
public: void send(char *str) { H::send(my(this, str)); }
};
#define H DiagnosticH // optional
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you can't modify X, I think the next best option is to do a regex replacement on your source to call your wrapper function instead. Even if it were possible to define a macro like that, it will lead to an unmaintainable nightmare.